# Not able to update image in SwiftUI with file on disk when update data in parent view

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I'm trying to update the image of this view when updating the variable of parent view but failed. The code is like this. I tried to update image in `ItemView` when updating the itemID in `ItemViewContainer` The `Text` in `ItemView` is updated but `image` not. The image is stuck on `itemID = 1`. How to update the image in `ItemView` when updating the `itemID` in its parent view.

```
struct ItemView: View {
    @State var image: UIImage?
    
    var id: Int
    
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        updateUI()
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        Task {
            await fetchImage()
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if let image = image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
            } else {
                // place holder view
                Image("empty_item")
                    .resizable()
            }
            // this can be updated
            Text(id.description)
        }
        .task {
            await fetchImage()
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchImage() async {
        // Read image on local file
        if let cacheImage = ImageCache.readImage(type: .item, id: id.description) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                image = cacheImage
            }
            return
        }
        // if there is not image on local disk, download from internet
        guard let newImage = await loadImage() else {
            return
        }
        // Save image to local disk
        ImageCache.saveImage(newImage, type: .item, id: id.description)
        // update image
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            image = newImage
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage() async -> UIImage? {
        guard let url = computeURL(),
              let (newImageData, _) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(from: url),
              let newImage = UIImage(data: newImageData) else {
            return nil
        }
        return newImage
    }
}

struct ItemViewContainer: View {
    @State var itemID = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        ItemView(id: itemID)
            .task {
                await changeItem()
            }
    }
    
    private func changeItem() async {
        for _ in 0...4 {
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
            // update itemID try to update image
            itemID += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ItemView` change the `id` property to be a binding

```
@Binding var id: Int
```

and also change the `.task` modifier to react to changes in `id` so it automatically executes when `id` changes.

```
.task(id: id) {
     await fetchImage()
}
```